# How to parse string date using date-fns lib

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I have a string date which looks like follows:

```
Mon Apr 12 2021 17:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

I need it to parse it to the following dd/MM/yyy format.

So my try is:

```
const date = 'Mon Apr 12 2021 17:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)';
const parsedDate = parse(date, 'E MMM d yyyy H:m:s' new Date());
const formattedDate = format(parsedDate, 'dd/MM/yyy');
```

But issue is in that part of the date: GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time).
What is the correct way to handel it?

Comment: It's a valid date string so you can call `new Date('Mon Apr 12 2021 17:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)')`

Comment: well, it was my first idea, and looks like it was actually correct, the issue was that some objects didn't have that property :), fixed now. I would accept your answer if you want :)